# How to change columns to rows

Tags: sql, union, unpivot

I have a question.

In SQL there is a table I have to code with a claim ID with Multiple error code. So it shows as follows

```
ClaimID    Error1  Error2  Error3 Error4
1234       300     301     302     303
```

and I want the error to show up in separate rows like

```
ClaimID  Error
1234     300
1234     301
1234     302
1234     303
```

How would I code this in SQL?  thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: sql-server, postgresql, oracle...?

Answer (score 2):

You want to *unpivot* the rows to column. The best solution depends on the database you are running. A cross-database approach is `union all`:

```
select claimID, error1 as error from mytable
union all select claimID, error2 from mytable
union all select claimID, error3 from mytable
union all select claimID, error4 from mytable
```

In databases that support lateral joins and the `values()` rows constructor, there are better options, that do not require scanning the table multiple times.

In Postgres:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values 
    (t.claimID, t.error1),
    (t.claimID, t.error2),
    (t.claimID, t.error3),
    (t.claimID, t.error4)
) as x(claimID, error)
```

In SQL Server, you would just replace `cross join lateral` with `cross apply`.

Comment: It is SQL server

Comment: @Lissette: my answer covers that.